# WPF Grid Splitter issue

Tags: wpf, gridsplitter

I have this control:

Image: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/999d1290-2d69-4cd0-9396-072e765e8364

[image]

How would I add GridSplitter near top arrow so when I drag splitter down, height of orange pipe will be increased. You can only drag down (up is not allowed)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="900">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="arrowLine" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="20" Width="1" Background="Black"/>
    <Polygon Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Fill="Black" Points="0,-6 10,-6 5,0" FillRule="Nonzero" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <!-- The gripper on the Top -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="40">
            <Rectangle x:Name="OrangeBar" Fill="#FFD61D2B">
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="OrangeBarShine">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFB141" Offset="0.172"/>
                        <GradientStop/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Polygon Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  Fill="Black" Points="0,6 10,6 5,0" FillRule="Nonzero" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Grid  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1" Background="Black"/>
    <Line Grid.Row="5" X1="25" Y1="0" X2="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Y2="20" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"></Line>
    <Line Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" X1="-25" Y1="20" X2="130" Y2="20" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black"></Line>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You don't have a GridSplitter in the XAML

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without moving the bar's top location, this is a bad idea. Even if you could get it to work, dragging is based on delta. And just a little drag will result in the bar suddenly becoming larger than the screen.

If you want to resize the bar and move it's location at the same time in equal amounts, consider binding the cell above the bar and the bar heights together.

Consider moving the splitter to below the bar. Then set the minimum height on the bar to the height whenever the height of the bar changes.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with making it bigger from the bottom?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />            
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="White"/>    
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Orange"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Background="White" 
        ShowsPreview="True"
        Height="5"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Background="White"/>
</Grid>
```